# How to inject same context in many different Django views?

Tags: django, mixins

I want to put info about one object in many views without repeating it in get_context_data in each view. As u understand i need a class with get_context_data inside, that i can mix with other views. 
Here in my example i want to see 'some_object' in context of UpdateAnotherObjectView:

```
class BaseObjectInfoView(View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(BaseObjectInfoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['some_object'] = SomeObjects.objects.get(pk=1)
        return context_data

class UpdateAnotherObjectView(BaseObjectInfo, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'create_object.html'
    form_class = AnotherObjectForm
    model = AnotherObjects

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(UpdateAnotherObjectView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['all_another_objects'] = AnotherObjects.objects.all()
        return context_data
```

it works, but get_context_data is not a part of parent 'View' class. May be i need more special class to inherit from in BaseObjectInfoView?

or maybe better to construct context with another method ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mixins don't need to be views, but it helps IDE's if they have the methods they're overriding.

Contexts are handled by `django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin` (details on [this very handy site](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.base/ContextMixin/)), So the class-based views way of things would be this:

```
from django.views import generic

class WebsiteCommonMixin(generic.base.ContextMixin):
    page_title = ''
    active_menu = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WebsiteCommonMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(dict(page_title=self.page_title, active_menu=self.active_menu))
        return context

class NewsListView(WebsiteCommonMixin, ListView):
    page_title = 'News list'
    active_menu = 'News'
    model = News
    paginate_by = 12
```

I do this for many projects and the simple views you have to create anyway, are fully declarative. And by simple, I mean that they can consist of mulitple mixins, all doing the hard stuff in either get_queryset, get_context_data or form_valid. More elaborate example, straight from a project:

```
class FeedbackMixin(object):
    message = 'Well Done!'

    def __init__(self):
        self._message_kwargs = {}
        super().__init__()

    def add_message_kwarg(self, name, value) -> None:
        self._message_kwargs[name] = value

    def format_message(self, kwargs) -> str:
        return self.message.format(**kwargs)

    def generate_message(self) -> None:
        msg = self.format_message(self._message_kwargs)
        messages.success(getattr(self, 'request'), msg)


class ModelFeedbackMixin(FeedbackMixin, generic.edit.ModelFormMixin):
    success_view_name = None
    success_url_kwargs = None

    def get_success_url_kwargs(self):
        return self.success_url_kwargs

    def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        success_url_kwargs = self.get_success_url_kwargs()
        if not self.success_view_name:
            url = super().get_success_url()
        elif success_url_kwargs is not None:
            url = reverse(self.success_view_name, kwargs=success_url_kwargs)
        else:
            if hasattr(self.object, 'slug'):
                url_kwargs = {'slug': self.object.slug}
            else:
                url_kwargs = {'pk': self.object.pk}
            url = reverse(self.success_view_name, kwargs=url_kwargs)
        return url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        self.generate_message()
        return response
```

Comment: It's very nice! But how can i manage with context mixin, if i need to place in context some objects depended from view kwargs, mentioned in url pattern (ex. 'object_pk') ? In my example i got object by pk=1, but pk mast be taken from url.

Comment: The pk is available in `self.kwargs` on the view. This is done by `View.as_view()`. But [SingleObjectMixin](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/SingleObjectMixin/) which is part of `DetailView` will do all the hard work for you if it is the main object of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way could be easier to read...

```
def add_context(func):
# this is a wrapper function
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        context_data = func(*args, **kwargs)
        context_data['some_object'] = SomeObjects.objects.get(pk=1)
        return context_data
return wrapper


class UpdateAnotherObjectView(BaseObjectInfo, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'create_object.html'
    form_class = AnotherObjectForm
    model = AnotherObjects

    @add_context
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['all_another_objects'] = AnotherObjects.objects.all()
        return kwargs
```