# How to activate users manually

Tags: django, django-registration

**Django 1.11.2**

**django-registration-redux==1.6**

I'm building an intranet website. And I'd like to control myself whether users are active or not. In Django admin there is such a possibility. But "Active" attribute is set to True automatically when a newly registered user confirms his/her email.

In other words what I'd like to do:
1) Let users register and reset passwords.
2) Admin of the site assigns the new user to a group. Users with the minimum permissions can only view. Special permissions allow edit, delete etc. But the user must be unable even to view anything without approval by the admin.

Now I'm planning to organize can_view permission for every model. The two above conditions will be performed by assigning the user to a group.

Well, this seems to be rather cumbersome. That "Active" attribute in admin is much more elegant. But "Active" is automatically set to True when the user confirms his/her email.

Could you give me a piece of advice here?

Comment: why are you going with so much complexities of a library. If you make it from scratch it would be really easy to control the behavior and it is really easy to implement.

Comment: Pardon, I can't catch your idea. What complexities? I'm not writing everything from scratch. I'll use django-registration-redux. But what is implemented there is not very suitable for me in case of that activation algorythm.

Comment: from complexities i meant you will be having more control over the flow if you have everything from scratch rather than you use dango registration redux.

Comment: I don't think. Writing a permission is simple. It really adds some code but doesn't add a complexity. Whereas writing a registration is not that easy.

Comment: writing a registration with email verification is way too easy task. It does not take more than 100 lines of code.

Comment: No, I don't think that it is a good idea. Maybe you could help me subclass the views of django-registration-redux so as not to switch that active attribute to True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's tempting, never use `is_active` to deny permissions. The flag is meant to be equivalent to "deleting a user". That also means the user cannot login (with default authentication backend). So it's not an **authorization** guard, but an **authentication** guard.

That said, if you don't grant permissions, users don't have them. So if you implement `can_view` and set it to guard the relevant models and views, then the user can log in, but cannot see anything you don't want them to (it's convenient for a user to see that she successfully logged in though :) ).

### Follow-up question from comments

It's fine to use one global permission that is checked per view. When using class based views, I recommend extending `LoginRequiredMixin`, tuck a few other goodies in a `IntranetCommonMixin` and have each view combine it with one of the generic base views. See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44741540/1600649).

The only reason you don't want to do it, is that it's tough to code exceptions on the rule, because the first "object" that says "yes", wins.

Comment: Thank you, Melvyn. Could you give me another piece of advice. Nowadays I know that if users are granted can_view, they can see anything. And I am not planning to change that so far. In this case I could organize just one can_view permission. Like 'home.can_view' and check it for every view on the site at all. Is it a good idea or should I create special can_view permissions for each model?